# Simple use of IF inside procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm creating a simple query, a simple select like `select x,y,z from etc etc` but in the software, there are `start date` and `end date`.

If the user fills in only the first date, then it will use a `where` clause like this:

```
where....
and...
and x.date >= Startdate
```

If the user fills in both dates, it will use:

```
where....
    and...
    and x.date between @Startdate and @enddate
```

If the user fills in only end date:

```
 where....
    and...
    and x.date < @enddate
```

I'm getting a syntax error with everything I'm trying to do.

```
 where....
        and...
        case when @startdate is not null and @enddate is null
           and x.date >= Startdate
```

Or even using `if`. What is the correct syntax for this? Or this is something programmers need to fix inside the software's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
WHERE....
AND...
AND (x.DATE>= @Startdate OR @Startdate IS NULL)
AND (x.DATE<= @enddate OR @enddate IS NULL)
```

Possibly with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog.